# Call different methods, from different repositories, in same transaction using Unit of work

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I am still learning UnitOfWork pattern and I am not comfortable with this yet. I found many examples but nothing is clear enough for my problem.
I  want use UnitOfWork with Ado.Net.
I have many repositories. I want call different methods from different repositories in same transaction using Unit of work.

For example a have this 2 repositories.

```
public class FirstRepository : IFirstRepository
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IImportConfiguration configuration;

        public FirstRepository(ILogger logger, IImportConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }   
        public int Save()
        {
            //Save to DB with Ado.Net
            return 1;
        }
    }

public class SecondRepository : ISecondRepository
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IImportConfiguration configuration;

        public SecondRepository(ILogger logger, IImportConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public int Update()
        {
            //Update in DB with Ado.Net
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

I want call functions Save() and Update() in same transaction.

```
using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
     firstRepository.Save(); 
     secondRepository.Update();

     _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

Problem is how to use same UnitOfWork in both repositories ? Only thing I can see is add additional parameter to functions

```
//in first repository
Save(IUnitOfWork uow)

//in second repository
Update(IUnitOfWork uow)
//****************************
using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
     firstRepository.Save(uow); 
     secondRepository.Update(uow);

     _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is ugly solution, because i must have this parameter in all functions that work with DB.
I am using Dependency injection. ILogger and  IImportConfiguration are injected with AutoFac. Maybe would be good to register all repositories in UnitOfWork? But how to do that? I cant have just one instance injected in all repositories.
Any idea?

Comment: Your repositories should have a factory as well, and you pass your unit of work through to that repository

Comment: Do you have any example? Factory for many repositories can be complicated if I am right?

Comment: creating one for ya!

Comment: Have a look now, I have done it off the top of my head, so there may be a few issues!

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to implement CompanyRepositoryFactory if I use DI ? I can't just do "new CompanyRepository(uow);". I have to resolve CompanyRepository somehow.

Comment: At the bottom of my answer I give you a sample with entity framework taken into account, did you want to know how to register these with a DI?

Comment: Yes, I need RepositoryFactory  with DI. Also I am using Ado.Net, not entity framework. I cannot just write 'new Repistory<T>(uow);' .

Comment: well to be honest with you, i've given you a fairly comprehensive solution, so you just need to work out the other bits yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        underlyingContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public UnitOfWork Create() 
    {
        // real creation logic
        return new UnitOfWork();
    }
}

public class CompanyRepository
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork uow;

    public CompanyRepository(UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        uow = uow;
    }

    public void Add(Company company)
    {
        uow.Companies.Add(company);
    }  
}

public class CompanyRepositoryFactory
{
    public Create(UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        new CompanyRepository(uow);
    }
}
```

Tying it all together:

```
var uow = new UnitOfWorkFactory().Create();
var companyRepository = new CompanyRepositoryFactory().Create(uow);
```

So to use DI, you need to create interfaces for all these.

The unit of work is based round some Data Layer connection, for example EF uses `DbContext` which you would use in the underlying `UnitOfWork` class.

Other things you can do is make `IUnitOfWork` (the interface) inherit `IDisposable` so you use the `using()`.

To make it so you don't have a hundred repository classes (although not really a bad thing) you can make it Generic, so `IRepository<T>` and `Repository<T>`

So for a generic repo and unit of work using EF.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    ProjectDbContext context;

    public UnitOfWork() {
        context = new ProjectDbContext();    
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<bool, t>> predicate)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory
{
    Lazy<UnitOfWork> lazyUOW = new Lazy<UnitOfWork>(() => new UnitOfWork());

    public UnitOfWork Create() 
    {
        // having the DI initialise as Singleton isn't enough.
        return lazyUOW.Value;
    }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        uow = uow;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        uow.Add(entity);
    }

    public List<T> AllBySomePredicate(Expression<Func<bool, T>> predicate)
    {
        return uow.Query(predicate).ToList();
    }  
}

public class RepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory 
{
    public Create<T>(UnitOfWork uow)
    {
        new Repistory<T>(uow);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
     private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory;
     private readonly IRepositoryFactory repoFactory;

     public CompanyController (
             IUnitOfWorkFactory uowFactory,
             IRepositoryFactory repoFactory)
     {
          uowFactory = uowFactory;
          repoFactory = repoFactory;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         using(var uow = uowFactory.Create()) 
         {
             var companyRepo = repoFactory.Create<Company>(uow);

             return View(companyRepo.AllBySomePredicate(x => x.CompanyJoined == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)));
         }
     }
}
```